# How to get code behind BindableProperty in view using xaml in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have implemented bindable property in contentview code behind. I want to access that code behind bindable property into view, my code is mentioned below, please refer,

**CustomControlView.xaml**

```
<ContentView.Content>
   <StackLayout>
      <Entry MyText="Text any message..." TextColor="Orange" />
   </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

**CustomControlView.xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class CustomControlView : ContentView
 {
    public string MyText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly BindableProperty MyTextProperty =
        BindableProperty.CreateAttached("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(CustomControlView), "", defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: MyTextPropertyChanged);

    private static void MyTextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (Entry)bindable;
        control.Text = newValue.ToString();
    }
 }
```

**MainView.xaml**(ContentPage)

```
 xmlns:view="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"

   <ContextPage.Content>
       <view:CustomControlView />
   </ContentPage.Content>
```

I want to set the MyText property into Entry. Please give any suggestion to me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reference your custom view in your XAML. For example, if your `CustomerControlView` is in `namespace MyApp.Controls`, you will need to reference in XAML:

```xml
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"
    x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">
...
</ContentPage>
```

You then call `CustomerControlView` like so:

```xml
<local:CustomerControlView 
    MyText="Text any message..." 
    TextColor="Orange" />
```

In the end, your XAML would look like:

```xml
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"
    x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
       <StackLayout>
          <local:CustomerControlView 
              MyText="Text any message..." 
              TextColor="Orange" />
       </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Just an FYI, in your code you call the class `CustomerControlView`, but in your `BindableProperty` you are referencing `CustomControlView`.

Comment: CustomControlView is a ContentView. In that CustomControlView there is a Entry, I want to set the MyText property into the Entry. This CustomControlView is implemented into MainPage(ContentPage).xaml

Comment: So you want to extend `Entry`?

Comment: Yes, But not only Entry, I want to create Bindable property to many UIElements

Comment: Hitesh's answer will work then, but you will have to implement that for every view you want to add your custom `BindableProperty` to.

Answer (score 0):

First Create Custom Control like this,

```
public class MyCustomEntry : Entry
{
    #region Property MyText

    /// <summary>
    /// Bindable Property MyText
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty MyTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
      nameof(MyText),
      typeof(string),
      typeof(MyCustomEntry),
      "",
      BindingMode.TwoWay,
      // validate value delegate
      // (sender,value) => true
      null,
      // property changed, delegate
      (sender,oldValue,newValue) => ((MyCustomEntry)sender).OnMyTextChanged(oldValue,newValue),
      // property changing delegate
      // (sender,oldValue,newValue) => {}
      null,
      // coerce value delegate 
      // (sender,value) => value
      null,
      // create default value delegate
      // () => Default(T)
      null
    );


    // <summary>
    // On MyText changed
    // </summary>
    // <param name = "oldValue" > Old Value</param>
    // <param name = "newValue" > New Value</param>
    protected virtual void OnMyTextChanged(object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        this.Text = newValue != null ? newValue.ToString() : oldValue.ToString();

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Property MyText
    /// </summary>
    public string MyText
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyTextProperty, value);
        }
    }
    #endregion


}
```

Then use it in your Content Page like this,

```
<local:MyCustomEntry 
MyText="Text any message..." 
TextColor="Orange" />
```

Comment: I want to create all the bindable properties in CustomControlView. By using the CustomControlView reference, i want to set the property in that view.